# Automatically set = and IS in Python psycopg2 sql module

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I have this snippet in Python using psycopg2:

```
spam = None    
command = sql.SQL("= {}").format(sql.Literal(spam))
```

Mogrifying the command gives "= NULL", which gives no results when included in the SQL query, since the query needs "IS NULL" to work.

(If spam is not None, but for example "eggs", "= 'eggs'" will work fine for the query.)

Is there a way to automatically switch between "IS" and "=" in the mogrified command, depending on whether the following argument is None or not None?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use `is distinct from` instead of `=` to include nulls in the comparison.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you! Did not get the idea to resolve it on the Postgres side.